# First time open app turns all time to tutorial screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to show a screen tutorial only first time you open the app.
But the problem is when i navigate to my app first time and go back to rootviewcontroller all time shows tutorial screen. And i want to show "Menu" screen.

How could i set like RootViewController my MenuViewController after tutorial screen?

Thank you!

I have this code in appdelegate.m :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ISFIRSTTIME"] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    controller = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else {
    controller = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialViewController" bundle:nil];
}
_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self.window setRootViewController:_navController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has `setBool:forKey:` and `boolForKey:` methods you can use instead of comparing a string to `@"NO"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like,

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ISFIRSTTIME"] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    controller = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else {
    controller = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialViewController" bundle:nil];
}
_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self.window setRootViewController:_navController];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Setting "ISFIRSTTIME" to "NO" : it will be "NO" after first time you open the app

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"ISFIRSTTIME"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thank you for all your support but doesn´t work. First time i open the app when i come back all time i have to come back with

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Goes to TutorialScreen and not to MenuScreen

Answer (score 1):

set in else condition,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"ISFIRSTTIME"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am doing like this in my one project,

```
NSString *identifier;
BOOL isSaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loginSaved"];
if (isSaved)
{
    identifier=@"home1";

}
else
{
    identifier=@"dis1";
}
UIStoryboard *    storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *screen = [storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];


[self.window setRootViewController:screen];
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the NO to your Nsuserdefault object in else condition
2. Compare it with the object not the method. 
   Like take bool isfirsttime = your NSuserdefault method.
   Use 
   if (isfirsttime)

   {}
   Else
   {}